# Disable RVM or use Ruby which was installed without RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

For rails application I had installed Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.11. And it was working fine. After that I have installed RVM and REE. 
So while running ruby script/server it's using REE. But now I want to use the older Ruby 1.8.7 which was installed without RVM.

Any Solution!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try `rvm use system` to use the system ruby which is not managed via. rvm.

Comment: This command works fine. But after restarts terminal still getting ruby loaded with rvm.

Comment: Restart? Do you mean for new terminals?

Comment: Yes new terminals or after restart my PC.

Comment: So then use the --default flag. RVM has a web site with docs on it, by the way.

Comment: I usually stick an rvm invocation at the end of my shell init files to select the appropriate ruby for my work. New shells run that and so I get what I need.

Comment: Here's what the command returns when you do that with current rvm:  
  
`RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.`

Comment: Can't help. I've ditched rvm for rbenv.

Answer (score 10):

This works!

This means to set the "system" ruby as default, you reset RVM's defaults as follows.

```
rvm reset
```

NOTE: it works only when there is no default ruby set:

```
rvm alias delete default
```

https://rvm.io/rubies/default/

Comment: This worked for me. In RVM if you have set default ruby version rvm use system jumps to  that version.

Answer (score 1):

I use `rbenv` and only installed `rvm` for some utilities it ships with. To temporarily disable rvm I used:

```
mv ~/.rvm ~/.silenced-rvm
```