# Library not loaded (libcrypto)

Tags: ruby, md5, sha1, rbenv, libcrypto

After updating `ruby` and `rubyenv` packages I'm facing an error. The `libcrypto` library is not loaded.

When executing the suggested command it seems that it is searching for `openssl` in ruby `/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1`. But on my system I use `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5`.

```
$ gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I used the above command to diagnose another error (maybe this helps):

```
$ bundle install --system
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.4
/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/digest.rb:16:in `const_missing': library not found for class Digest::MD5 -- digest/md5 (LoadError)
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems/remote.rb:26:in `cache_slug'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:107:in `cache_path'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:83:in `compact_index_client'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:630:in `warn_on_outdated_bundler'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:15:in `ensure in start'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:16:in `start'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
mdm:ios si$ export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
mdm:ios si$ bundle install --system
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.4
/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/digest.rb:16:in `const_missing': library not found for class Digest::MD5 -- digest/md5 (LoadError)
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems/remote.rb:26:in `cache_slug'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:107:in `cache_path'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:83:in `compact_index_client'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:630:in `warn_on_outdated_bundler'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:15:in `ensure in start'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:16:in `start'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What happens if you try what the error message suggested? `gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2`?

Comment: Tried that, seems that I have a linking problem (see updated question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test:

```
rvm 2.6.5
```

To determine that `ruby-2.6.5` was not installed, so I installed it:

```
rvm install "ruby-2.6.5"
```

Comment: Ok. Good. This should work also if you wish to stick with RVM. Remember to set the new Ruby as default after you install.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are using the system Ruby from `/usr/local/` yet the error messages are from an RVM installation.

You need to either uninstall RVM, or set the system Ruby as default for RVM:

```
rvm --default use system
```

More discussion here:
[Disable RVM or use Ruby which was installed without RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660605/disable-rvm-or-use-ruby-which-was-installed-without-rvm/5660661)