# Ruby: LoadError - library not found for class Digest::SHA1 -- digest/sha1

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, rbenv, podfile

When running `pod install` it runs into a problem when installing `yoga`. Seems to be a problem with my ruby environment?

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Permission-Camera` from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Camera.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Permission-LocationAlways` from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/LocationAlways.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Permission-LocationWhenInUse` from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/LocationWhenInUse.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RNPermissions` from `../node_modules/react-native-permissions`
Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native/`
Fetching podspec for `yoga` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`
```

#### Command

```
/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/pod install
```

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.5.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
    RubyGems : 2.5.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
       Xcode : 11.2.1 (11B500)
         Git : git version 2.24.0
Ruby lib dir : /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 7f8d90dc76a619c74dfe5b8d17317599f6175fc3
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'default' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Pods for default
  pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'

  # Pods for ReactPushNotifications - Add these lines
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  # Pods for react-native-permissions
  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
end
```

#### Error

```
LoadError - library not found for class Digest::SHA1 -- digest/sha1
/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/digest.rb:16:in `const_missing'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:566:in `checksum'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:641:in `block in generate_version_locking_dependencies'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:640:in `reject'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:640:in `generate_version_locking_dependencies'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:87:in `analyze'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1837

Comment: Yes, the output is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/59033566/5185570

Answer (score 37):

For me the me problem started after an unsolicited system update.

Uninstalling ruby and installing it again solved the issue:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.5.1
rbenv install 2.5.1
```

Comment: For me, I had to run `rvm reinstall ...` (since I'm using RVM instead of `rbenv`).

Answer (score 5):

there is issue with ruby version.
Install latest

```
brew install ruby
```

below command will overwrite the previous version

```
brew link --overwrite ruby
```

close this terminal and open new terminal.check your version

```
ruby -v
```

check issue resolve or not

```
ruby -r digest/sha1 -e 'p Digest::SHA1'
```

expected output : Digest::SHA1

Comment: I'm getting the ruby version `ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin19]` and the expected output `Digest::SHA1`. But the error when doing `pod install` is still the same in the same terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

Since this worked me, I am posting it as a comment.

After running

```
rbenv uninstall 2.5.1
```

if the below command is giving you an error (with ruby not installing)

```
rbenv install 2.5.1
```

maybe run this (for mac path)

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2q rbenv install 2.3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working on a **Rails 4.2.3** application with **Ruby 2.2.3** and **RVM** in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

I was getting the error below when I try running the `rails server` command:

> /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/digest.rb:15:in `const_missing': library not found for class Digest::SHA1 -- digest/sha1 (LoadError)

I found out that the issue was caused by this library - `libssl-dev`

All I had to do was to uninstall the ruby version:

```
rvm uninstall 2.2.3
```

**Note**: Replace `rvm` with `rbenv` if you're using **rbenv** for package management

And then installed the ruby version again:

```
rvm install 2.2.3
```

This removed the `libssl-dev` library and installed `libssl1.0-dev` library.

Finally, I opened the application and installed all my gems again:

```
bundle install
```

**Note**: This installed the rails gem for the project as well

Finally, I started my rails server again:

```
rails server
```

and everything worked fine this time.