# Brew update breaks "Rails s" ( Open SSL + LoadError - library not found for class Digest::SHA1 — digest/sha1 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, openssl, homebrew, rbenv

Following a recent update of Homebrew, I can not use the "rails s" command anymore. Apparently, it is a well known issue. Since macOS decided to drop OpenSSL and switched to LibreSSL, that error poped up a lot. Thus I applied the common answer to this :

```
brew uninstall openssl; 
brew uninstall openssl; 
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Once this done, another issue appeared: "LoadError - library not found for class Digest::SHA1 ".
There again, I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033798/loaderror-library-not-found-for-class-digestsha1-digest-sha1) to this issue and applied it. Which brought me back to square one with my original issue with OpenSSL.

How can I get it running in a proper way so my "rails s" does not break anymore ?

Thank you in advance!!!

Stack:
 - ruby 2.7.0p0 ; 
 - Mac Os High Sierra

Comment: I use to have the same problem every time I update openssl, this works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184347/5215927

Comment: Thanks for your input @mr_sudaca , but I still get this error "const_missing': library not found for class Digest::SHA1 -- digest/sha1 (LoadError)"

And I wasn't able to resolve it through this process : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033798/loaderror-library-not-found-for-class-digestsha1-digest-sha1

I feel like I'm stuck in an infinite loop !

Comment: Well after a thousand attempt, and a good night of sleep, your fix finally worked @mr_sudaca!  Not sure why now and not before, but eh... Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib/59184347#59184347) works for me.
Side note, I had to restart my mac for it to works. No idea why closing and opening a new session of my terminal was not enough though !